# WAMP - Ignore subfolder, but request files inside it

Tags: apache, wamp

I am trying to setup WAMP to my directory tree. I can't edit the tree, since I work as a freelance developer and my client requires me to do it like this.

My tree:

`C:\Users\ME\Sites\skolind\PROJECT\assets` --> my uncompiled files.
`C:\Users\ME\Sites\skolind\PROJECT\markup\FILES\` --> my compiled files.

In `C:\Users\ME\Sites\skolind\PROJECT\markup\FILES\` I have folders: scripts, styles, static.

I have made a vhost for PROJECT.skolind, with DocumentRoot as: `C:/Users/ME/Sites/skolind/PROJECT/markup/FILES/`.

This works great, and my .html files are served to me, but, I need my files from scripts, styles and static to be requested as /scripts/bundle.js, /styles/styles.css and /static/xx.jpg. Right now it's requested as /FILES/scripts/bundle.js which is incorrect. The webpack build builds the files into /FILES/, because, yeah, who knows :)

Is there a way to "fool" the server to strip the /FILES/ and just pick from /scripts/ and so on?

I am not sure if it makes sense, but if you need more info, let me know, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this my self by using a slightly different mindset. I discovered "VirtualDocumentRoot" which allowed me to have this as my config. This helps me achieve what I wanted.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/Users/YOUR_USER/Sites/YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER/%1/markup/"
  ServerName sites.YOUR_USER
  ServerAlias *.YOUR_USER
  <Directory "C:/Users/YOUR_USER/Sites/PROJECT_FOLDER/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```